# Communicating between independent components react

Tags: reactjs

I have been facing a problem, I would like to write a div every time a specific button is clicked, but the button is in one component and the menu in which I want the div to be created is in another component as well , and both main components are in one component, is there a way of making this happen? So the structure of it all is something like this:

This is the root component with the smaller components in it:

```js
export class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="Body">
        <div id="SideBar" ><SideMenu/></div>
          <MenuCocktails/>
          <MenuBeers/>
          <MenuVines/>
          <MenuLemonades/>
          <MenuSoftDrinks/>
          <MenuCollection/>
          <MenuCharger/>
        <div id="BottomMenu"><BottomMenu/></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

this is the menu that I wanted to div to be created in:

```js
export class BottomMenu extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      shown: ''
    };
  }

  toggleMenu = () => {
    this.setState({shown: this.state.shown ? '' : 'visible'});
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button
          id="button"
          className={this.state.shown}
          onClick={this.toggleMenu}
        >
          My Cart
        </button>

        <div id="Header" className={this.state.shown}>
          <button id="CheckOutButton">Check Out</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is one of the components with the button:

```js
import React from "react";
import styles from "./MenuCocktails.css";
import plus from "./plus.png";

export class NiğdeGazozu extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
    <div id="menu-items-1">
      <div id="item-name">NIĞDE GAZOZU</div>
      <div id ="price-item">8 TL</div>
      <button id="plusbutton"><img src={plus}/></button>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a parent that renders both components and passes props to each child.

Comment: Would the root component in this situation be considered as the parent component ? Since its loading the other components as well ?

Comment: well, I wouldn't keep state in the root component. Just make another component that composes the other two components

Comment: So your suggestion is to make another component with containing the menu component and the other components and then put it in the root component?

Comment: I agree with @AndrewLi or use Redux

Comment: I really don't know much about redux , how difficult would it be to learn and implement here?